# $PATH variable is being overwritten. Where? Why?

Tags: linux, path, environment-variables

Have a system-wide environment variable setup in /etc/profile.d/myvars.sh.  The root account user (mint) can access the variables just fine.  A second administrator (admin2) cannot display the correct $PATH variable.

```
## /etc/profile.d/myvars.sh ##
export TESTVAR=/var/opt
export PATH=$TESTVAR:$PATH
```

`printenv` displays the correct value for TESTVAR but PATH does not contain my changes.  These are the only changes I have made to the server.

Any idea why?  This works for the main admin but not the additional second admin.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in must create a new session.

`su - username` will switch the environment variables to the new user.
`su username` will not.

When logging in as the 2nd admin, use
`su - admin2`

For more details, read [Linux su command](http://www.linfo.org/su.html).